# Unsubcribe a list a bunch of people

Tags: marketing-cloud

I want to unsubscribe a group of people in Marketing Cloud and I only see the option of unsubscribing manually and individually from All Subscribers.

thanks!

Comment: Hi Daniel, how would you like to unsubscribe them alternatively if those two options are not ideal e.g. SSJS or import process?

Answer (score 3):

Daniel - first create a .csv of the subscribers you'd like to unsubscribe, either by a data filter or query. Make sure your .csv file has a column titled "Status" and for every subscriber you'd like to unsubscribe make sure their status is marked as Unsubscribed. Then import that list of subscribers back into All Subscribers and make sure your mappings are correct.

Follow the processes here: [Import Subscribers into Marketing Cloud from a File](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_import_subscribers_from_file.htm&type=5)

There's other methods to do handle this, but an export/import is probably the easiet to master first.